# How do you correctly and quickly compare Datarows / Datatables?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datatable, datarow

Update: to explain what type of Datatables I Am comparing-
"Compare two Datatables with the same columns, one Datatable is being pulled form an external server and inserted Initially, from then onwards only last 6 months of records are pulled off external database (for various reasons) , and the data is compared with local data (for a 6 month date range) to see if a DataRow has changed,needs to be deleted or added where the Row Identifier (PKey)which is essentially the SalesID + LineRow match and other columns are values to be compared to see if that row needs to be re-added/deleted because incoming columns are different to current columns and also delete rows where the incoming data does not contain those rows

so basically I want a
Exclusive Left Join [to insert that data]
and
Exclusive Right Join [to delete that data]
"

I have been doing some database coding as well as JSON pulling and I want to know what is the standard way / correct way of doing things , I started with 2 hour compare times (on dummy DB table) down to 1 hour to 1 secs (after applying my janky method to DB table Compare) and then finally used it on live pull with what seems to be correct and consistent results and so I started doing testing on Dummy data with it going from 1 hour to 26 minutes to finally <1 seconds (using my own janky way), Table sizes tested and assumed are between 100,000 & 200,000 rows
so lets go through the standard methods I tried and then go onto the janky solution I Made.

The first and obvious idea was to use two `ForEach` iterations (even mentally this seemed it would be slow however I thought it wouldn't be that bad considering how quick Add is, and how quickly you can compare JSON Tokens when iterating through Jarrays). Code was something like the following:

```
DataTable dtQueryItemsDiff = dtItems.Clone();
DataTable dtItemsDiff = dtItems.Clone();

int maxRowCountCache = dtItems.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<String>("Date"))).ThenBy(row => row.Field<String>("Name")).Count();
int rowcountCCache = 0;
var query = dtQuery.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<String>("Date"))).ThenBy(row => row.Field<String>("Name"));
foreach (DataRow drDTI in dtItems.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<String>("Date"))).ThenBy(row => row.Field<String>("Name")))
{
    int innerrowcount = 0;
    bool rowfound = false;
    if (query.Count() != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow drDTQ in query)
        {
            if (drDTI["SalesID"].ToString() == drDTI["SalesID"].ToString() && drDTI["LineNumber"].ToString() == drDTI["LineNumber"].ToString())
            {
                rowfound = true;
                break;
            }
            innerrowcount++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dtItemsDiff.ImportRow(drDTI);
        continue;
    }
    if (rowfound == true)
    {
        orderedDtquery.ElementAt(innerrowcount).Delete();
    }
    else
    {
        dtItemsDiff.ImportRow(drDTI);
    }
    rowcountCCache++;
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        lblDataLoadC.Text = rowcountCCache.ToString() + " / " + maxRowCountCache.ToString();
    }));
}
if (query.Count() != 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow drDTQ in query)
    {
        dtQueryItemsDiff.ImportRow(drDTQ);
    }
}
```

This took quite a long time about an 1H (1 Hour) to 1.5H depending on data how it was ordered etc. The benefit was that I could granularly change the code and it gave me Non-matched data in both tables, also it reduced query size searched but this wasn't fast enough for me so then I tried Linq searching where I didn't reduce list size as a I went (it was slower to delete then search then it was to just search) and this took about ~40-50 mins and looked like:

```
int maxRowCountCache = dtItems.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<String>("Date"))).ThenBy(row => row.Field<String>("Name")).Count();
int rowcountCCache = 0;
dtItems.AcceptChanges();
foreach (DataRow drDTI in dtItems.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<String>("Date"))).ThenBy(row => row.Field<String>("Name")))
{
    var checkIfRecordInIDB = progSettings.query.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("CardRecordID") == drDTI["CardRecordID"].ToString()
    && row.Field<string>("Date") == drDTI["Date"].ToString() && row.Field<string>("SaleID") == drDTI["SaleID"].ToString()
    && row.Field<string>("ItemID") == drDTI["ItemID"].ToString() && row.Field<Int64>("LineNumber") == Convert.ToInt64(drDTI["LineNumber"].ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
    if (checkIfRecordInIDB != null)
    {
        drDTI.Delete();
    }
    rowcountCCache++;
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        lblDataLoadC.Text = rowcountCCache.ToString() + " / " + maxRowCountCache.ToString();
    }));
}
dtItems.AcceptChanges();
```

Benefit of this is its slightly more lazy, faster and concise, however it only gives you data in one table much like Except does and that is exactly what I tried next using ~100,000 rows of dummy data, this took 26 minutes and 35 seconds.

```
dtItems.Rows.Clear();
query.Rows.Clear();
Thread start = new Thread(timerAndUIupdate);
start.Start();

dtItems.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "72421ee8-459b-46fb-bf5a-f51e80976e5a", "Pioneer 1kg (FT), RRP $42", "100115", 1, 25.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "8885a911-8d32-4dfe-93e5-2e453fd54db9", "Decaf Beans 250g FT", "1002302", 2, 2.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "e3aa4b15-b774-4f6a-ac21-77fa05a4332f", "P&R Cups 06oz (1000)", "30056", 3, 1.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "51e1a867-4079-4a3c-9ddc-e93d87d80b46", "P&R Cups 12oz (1000)", "30058", 4, 1.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "72421ee8-459b-46fb-bf5a-f51e80976e5a", "Pioneer 1kg (FT), RRP $42", "100115", 1, 25.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "8885a911-8d32-4dfe-93e5-2e453fd54db9", "Decaf Beans 250g FT", "1002302", 2, 2.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "e3aa4b15-b774-4f6a-ac21-77fa05a4332f", "P&R Cups 06oz (1000)", "30056", 3, 1.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "51e1a867-4079-4a3c-9ddc-e93d87d80b46", "P&R Cups 12oz (1000)", "30058", 4, 1.0, "N");
for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
{
    dtItems.Rows.Add("Bennett St Dairy", "ed0c8d30-6469-4e13-af5a-36d7357a4a70", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "8b909a4b-a07b-4a06-bebc-6a3387433aaf", "c8cc1115-da02-42cf-b427-accc1b6d07e3", "Trailblazer 1Kg, RRP $44", "10011", i, (i * 4), "N");
    query.Rows.Add("Bennett St Dairy", "ed0c8d30-6469-4e13-af5a-36d7357a4a70", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "8b909a4b-a07b-4a06-bebc-6a3387433aaf", "c8cc1115-da02-42cf-b427-accc1b6d07e3", "Trailblazer 1Kg, RRP $44", "10011", i, (i * 4), "N");
}
dtItems.Rows.Add("Air Coffee International Cafe Pty Ltd", "bb4fa724-9759-4c60-93fe-70fbdfd00417", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "b972f020-3740-4ef2-941f-78b1a9edefa8", "0be54733-ac0e-43f9-8ea5-204c7cdb5f48", "Custom 1kg", "100116", 1, 4.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Allure Cafe & Co.", "f76f383f-e9f4-45c9-bb93-81102629b9c3", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "2ad0667f-2254-4df5-8b24-eb36736cabb0", "6edc584b-a8eb-4f0b-a449-dbcb76a40a24", "Porter St 1Kg, RRP $40", "100111", 1, 10.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "6edc584b-a8eb-4f0b-a449-dbcb76a40a24", "Porter St 1Kg, RRP $40", "100111", 1, 30.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "51e1a867-4079-4a3c-9ddc-e93d87d80b46", "P&R Cups 12oz (1000)", "30058", 2, 12.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "401ce902-e158-4f21-85a5-3312c32457fc", "Lids 06/08/12oz (White) (1000)", "30062", 3, 7.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "9b80c825-6e9f-4f6b-9c77-f3378cc220e4", "4-Cup Cardboard Holders (300)", "41003", 4, 1.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "ea4c906e-fab1-4b15-8845-619f20e53c6a", "Organic Panela 1kg", "20014", 5, 2.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "bb3e1c10-9e67-46d3-99b4-17df45dead90", "Chocolate Powder 1Kg, RRP $25", "20034", 6, 1.0, "N");

query.Rows.Add("Aussie Bites Cafe", "30389aca-9089-4b37-9a1e-5fbc3c2af485", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "85df1af6-3d1e-4e04-8fe9-d90462a59d4c", "ea89ade4-c7ff-4d79-abcd-dcdbb8122562", "X Blend 1Kg, RRP $40", "100112", 1, 4.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Aussie Bites Cafe", "30389aca-9089-4b37-9a1e-5fbc3c2af485", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "85df1af6-3d1e-4e04-8fe9-d90462a59d4c", "21fe57ad-08f9-4c8b-81d0-d7b88b291571", "webfreight", "webfreight", 2, 1.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "6edc584b-a8eb-4f0b-a449-dbcb76a40a24", "Porter St 1Kg, RRP $40", "100111", 1, 30.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "51e1a867-4079-4a3c-9ddc-e93d87d80b46", "P&R Cups 12oz (1000)", "30058", 2, 1.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "401ce902-e158-4f21-85a5-3312c32457fc", "Lids 06/08/12oz (White) (1000)", "30062", 3, 2.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "9b80c825-6e9f-4f6b-9c77-f3378cc220e4", "4-Cup Cardboard Holders (300)", "41003", 4, 1.0, "N");
Stopwatch pullTime = new();
pullTime.Start();

BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    lblTimerAddRowEnd.Text = "Start Time,Except: " + pullTime.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff");
}));

var orderedDtItems = dtItems.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<String>("Date"))).ThenBy(row => row.Field<String>("Name"));
var orderedDtquery = query.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<String>("Date"))).ThenBy(row => row.Field<String>("Name"));
DataTable excepteditems = orderedDtItems.Except(orderedDtquery, DataRowComparer.Default).CopyToDataTable();

BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    labelControl1.Text = "End Time,Except: " + pullTime.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff");
}));

BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    dgvResults.DataSource = excepteditems;
    btnStart.Enabled = true;
    simpleButton1.Enabled = true;
}));
```

With this updater code for UI (this was threaded and used for all test comparisons):

```
private void timerAndUIupdate()
{
    Stopwatch pullTime = new();
    pullTime.Start();
    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            lblTimer.Text = "Timer: " + pullTime.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff");
            Application.DoEvents();
        }));
    } while (btnStart.Enabled == false);
    pullTime.Stop();
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        lblTimer.Text = "Timer: " + pullTime.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff");
        Application.DoEvents();
    }));
}
```

And results on Winforms looked like this:

[image: Winforms Window]

Then I did my janky way and the results were very fast and seemed quite accurate, and because it only took a fractions of a second I could perform this multiple times to get, New rows , Old rows not in pull that should not be deleted and Old Rows that should be Deleted -> code looked like this

```
dtItems.Rows.Clear();
query.Rows.Clear();
Thread start = new Thread(timerAndUIupdate);
start.Start();

      
dtItems.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "72421ee8-459b-46fb-bf5a-f51e80976e5a", "Pioneer 1kg (FT), RRP $42", "100115", 1, 25.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "8885a911-8d32-4dfe-93e5-2e453fd54db9", "Decaf Beans 250g FT", "1002302", 2, 2.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "e3aa4b15-b774-4f6a-ac21-77fa05a4332f", "P&R Cups 06oz (1000)", "30056", 3, 1.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "51e1a867-4079-4a3c-9ddc-e93d87d80b46", "P&R Cups 12oz (1000)", "30058", 4, 1.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "72421ee8-459b-46fb-bf5a-f51e80976e5a", "Pioneer 1kg (FT), RRP $42", "100115", 1, 25.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "8885a911-8d32-4dfe-93e5-2e453fd54db9", "Decaf Beans 250g FT", "1002302", 2, 2.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "e3aa4b15-b774-4f6a-ac21-77fa05a4332f", "P&R Cups 06oz (1000)", "30056", 3, 1.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("4 Beans Cafe", "2af0f4bf-52ea-44fb-b1b3-36181fe7bfdf", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "7fc4f98a-35af-4da3-afe3-f7cfcd922ea7", "51e1a867-4079-4a3c-9ddc-e93d87d80b46", "P&R Cups 12oz (1000)", "30058", 4, 1.0, "N");
for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
{
    dtItems.Rows.Add("Bennett St Dairy", "ed0c8d30-6469-4e13-af5a-36d7357a4a70", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "8b909a4b-a07b-4a06-bebc-6a3387433aaf", "c8cc1115-da02-42cf-b427-accc1b6d07e3", "Trailblazer 1Kg, RRP $44", "10011", i, (i * 4), "N");
    query.Rows.Add("Bennett St Dairy", "ed0c8d30-6469-4e13-af5a-36d7357a4a70", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "8b909a4b-a07b-4a06-bebc-6a3387433aaf", "c8cc1115-da02-42cf-b427-accc1b6d07e3", "Trailblazer 1Kg, RRP $44", "10011", i, (i * 4), "N");
}
dtItems.Rows.Add("Air Coffee International Cafe Pty Ltd", "bb4fa724-9759-4c60-93fe-70fbdfd00417", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "b972f020-3740-4ef2-941f-78b1a9edefa8", "0be54733-ac0e-43f9-8ea5-204c7cdb5f48", "Custom 1kg", "100116", 1, 4.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Allure Cafe & Co.", "f76f383f-e9f4-45c9-bb93-81102629b9c3", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "2ad0667f-2254-4df5-8b24-eb36736cabb0", "6edc584b-a8eb-4f0b-a449-dbcb76a40a24", "Porter St 1Kg, RRP $40", "100111", 1, 10.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "6edc584b-a8eb-4f0b-a449-dbcb76a40a24", "Porter St 1Kg, RRP $40", "100111", 1, 30.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "51e1a867-4079-4a3c-9ddc-e93d87d80b46", "P&R Cups 12oz (1000)", "30058", 2, 12.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "401ce902-e158-4f21-85a5-3312c32457fc", "Lids 06/08/12oz (White) (1000)", "30062", 3, 7.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "9b80c825-6e9f-4f6b-9c77-f3378cc220e4", "4-Cup Cardboard Holders (300)", "41003", 4, 1.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "ea4c906e-fab1-4b15-8845-619f20e53c6a", "Organic Panela 1kg", "20014", 5, 2.0, "N");
dtItems.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "bb3e1c10-9e67-46d3-99b4-17df45dead90", "Chocolate Powder 1Kg, RRP $25", "20034", 6, 1.0, "N");
        
query.Rows.Add("Aussie Bites Cafe", "30389aca-9089-4b37-9a1e-5fbc3c2af485", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "85df1af6-3d1e-4e04-8fe9-d90462a59d4c", "ea89ade4-c7ff-4d79-abcd-dcdbb8122562", "X Blend 1Kg, RRP $40", "100112", 1, 4.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Aussie Bites Cafe", "30389aca-9089-4b37-9a1e-5fbc3c2af485", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-01", "85df1af6-3d1e-4e04-8fe9-d90462a59d4c", "21fe57ad-08f9-4c8b-81d0-d7b88b291571", "webfreight", "webfreight", 2, 1.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "6edc584b-a8eb-4f0b-a449-dbcb76a40a24", "Porter St 1Kg, RRP $40", "100111", 1, 30.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "51e1a867-4079-4a3c-9ddc-e93d87d80b46", "P&R Cups 12oz (1000)", "30058", 2, 1.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "401ce902-e158-4f21-85a5-3312c32457fc", "Lids 06/08/12oz (White) (1000)", "30062", 3, 2.0, "N");
query.Rows.Add("Mad Hatter Wine Co", "49340e5f-c7ef-41d9-9f1b-200711e6e629", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-28", "e16cbbac-c319-45f3-ac53-89d979fbcdc1", "9b80c825-6e9f-4f6b-9c77-f3378cc220e4", "4-Cup Cardboard Holders (300)", "41003", 4, 1.0, "N");

Stopwatch pullTime = new();
pullTime.Start();

BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    lblTimerAddRowEnd.Text = "Start Time,Except: " + pullTime.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff");
}));
var orderedDtItems = dtItems.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<String>("Date"))).ThenBy(row => row.Field<String>("Name"));
var orderedDtquery = query.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<String>("Date"))).ThenBy(row => row.Field<String>("Name"));
      
dtOnlyNewRows.Rows.Clear();
HashSet<String> orderedDtItemsHS = new();
HashSet<String> orderedDtqueryHS = new();
HashSet<String> orderedDtItemsHSRemains = new();
HashSet<String> orderedDtqueryHSRemains = new();
foreach (DataRow dr in orderedDtquery)
{
    orderedDtqueryHSRemains.Add(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
    orderedDtqueryHS.Add(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
}
foreach (DataRow dr in orderedDtItems)
{
    orderedDtItemsHSRemains.Add(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
    orderedDtItemsHS.Add(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
    bool added = orderedDtqueryHSRemains.Add(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
    if (added == false)
    {
        orderedDtqueryHSRemains.Remove(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
    }
    else if (added == true)
    {
        dtOnlyNewRows.ImportRow(dr);
        orderedDtqueryHSRemains.Remove(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
    }
}

foreach (DataRow dr in orderedDtquery)
{
    bool added = orderedDtItemsHSRemains.Add(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
    if (added == false)
    {
        orderedDtItemsHSRemains.Remove(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
    }
    else if (added == true)
    {
        DateTime rowTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["date"].ToString());
        if (rowTime <= MonthCutOff)
        {
            dtOnlyLeftoverRows.ImportRow(dr);
        }
        else
        {
            dtOnlyDeleteRows.ImportRow(dr);
        }
        orderedDtItemsHSRemains.Remove(dr["CardRecordID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["SaleID"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["ItemID"].ToString()
        + "⌁" + dr["LineNumber"].ToString() + "⌁" + dr["Quantity"].ToString());
    }
}

Debug.WriteLine(dtOnlyNewRows.Rows.Count.ToString());
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    labelControl1.Text = "End Time,Except: " + pullTime.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff");
}));
pullTime.Stop();
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    dgvRowsRemaing.DataSource = dtOnlyLeftoverRows;
    dgvResults.DataSource = dtOnlyNewRows;
    dgvDeleteRows.DataSource = dtOnlyDeleteRows;
    btnStart.Enabled = true;
}));
```

And the end result looked as follows:

[image: Winforms Window]

After all this explanation comes my questions:

1. What did I do wrong in the other methods, can they be made faster?
2. How should I compare Datatables, if my janky methods is not OK?
3. As long as it works and is fast even if janky, is it OK?
4. What are the possible problems with my janky method?

Edited: 2021-08-03 11:25 PM AEST(Australian Eastern Standard Time)

the Code Juris wrote is Neater and Much Quicker,
What it looks like when applied to my dummy data
[Windows Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YRqx.png)

3 x quicker , less messy code, way shorter
this was exactly what I was looking for thank you

Comment: In all that you never really clearly said what "compare a datatable" means. I'm sure I could eventually work it out it by reading the code but base datatables code tends to be a horrific mess of casting and string column access. Do you mean "perform a full outer join on two datatables and then look for all the places where the equivalent (same column name?) values in each table differ"?

Comment: so basically I want a 
Exclusive Left Join [to insert that data]
and
Exclusive Right Join [to delete that data]

Comment: I Updated my original post

Comment: And are you happy to do this by primary key alone or must all the data be compared for changes in a match (and which side wins)? For a left of `[{ID:1,Name:Mark},{ID:2,Name:Luke},{ID:3,Name:John}]` and a right of `[{ID:2,Name:Luke},{ID:3,Name:Mary},{ID:4,Name:Mark}]` what will be the final state  (note; ID 3 Name has changed)

Comment: thought Pkey was enough, but i dont want intersecting data to be rewritten (for various reasons) also there is no true Pkey as data is being mined from MYOB in a set model(out of my control) but a Logical Pkey exists by combining 2 columns-> 
so I want to compare data based on rest of the columns , to see if incoming rows should be added or is already present for rows where Pkey Is not present in local DB and for remaining rows  -> if they share the same Pkey the Right side data is deleted i.e. Left side wins 
so just as you have demonstrated {ID:3,Name:John} will replace {ID:3,Name:Mary}

Comment: So e.g. the left is from a file that shall be merged into the db and the right is the db; file's new records not in db are added to d, file's records that are existing in db are updated, records in db but not file are deleted from db

Comment: yes that seems right , but "records in db but not file are deleted from db" are based on a cut off date

Comment: OK, sounds like a separate implementation detail  - i'm not sure if you mean that theyre only deleted from db if theyre older or if theyre younger than the date, but i'll leav that as out of scope

Comment: How about this as a completely different solution.  Skip `DataTable` and instead work in `List<ClassThatMatchesYourSchema>` and Dapper.  You are doing things like `drDTI["SalesID"]` inside foreach loops. That requires a string lookup (to find which column) on each cell in the DataTable, over and over.  Instead, create a class that matches your schema.  Add the comparison logic inside that class (where it belongs), perhaps by implementing `IComparable` and/or `IEquatable`.  Then use Dapper (which is really fast, way faster than `DataAdapter.Fill`) and go from there.

Comment: well because ->
1. Searlizing to an ORM, from JArray or JSON took way longer then iterating through the tokens while adding them to a Table/List(string only)
2. if so ArrayLists better, 5x cheaper to enumerate through (when using ForEach on List or Table),Easily Parallelized, wanted to be lazy using Add Remove, Performance differences in enumeration Without Comparison & With Just access was also negligible
3. for this many rows enumeration times are not much different between Lists and Tables
4. Am using SQL Adapter Fill Table for DB Data
5. String lookup on Ienumerable DataRow not Table

Comment: 6. Dapper is actually 2ms slower than SQL DataAdapter.Fill

all in all combination of: laziness, size of code/solution, scope of project, default thinking -> one of the reasons I posted this question, so I have a better understanding, of what objects are best for what situations , what's performant, what's slow, what is the least coding Required (which is another reason I really like Caius answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this by indexing the datatables with a pair of dictionaries. DataTable can have primary keys defined and perform fast lookups that use dictionaries internally but in general working with datatables is pretty ugly stuff so no point adding to it with more PK ugly

So we have some datatable on the right, and it's downlaoded from a DB, and you have decided that the "Foo" and "Bar" columns are the PK. Foo is a string, Bar is an int:

```
Dim rIndex = new Dictionary(Of (ValueTuple(Of String, Integer), DataRow)

For Each r as DataRow In rightDt.Rows
  Dim key = ( r.Field(Of String)("Foo"), r.Field(Of Integer)("Bar") )
  rIndex(key) = r
Next r
```

And we have some file that's been read into the left datatable. The file's columns happen to be called Wit (string) and Woo (int)

```
Dim lIndex = new Dictionary(Of (ValueTuple(Of String, Integer), DataRow)

For Each r as DataRow In leftDt.Rows
  Dim key = (r.Field(Of String)("Wit"), r.Field(Of Integer)("Woo") )
  lIndex(key) = r
Next r
```

Now it's probably going to make life easy if we stash the keys into a hashset too as we go; this represents the union of the left and the right

```
Dim allKeys as New HashSet(Of ValueTuple(Of String, Integer))

Dim rIndex = new Dictionary(Of (ValueTuple(Of String, Integer), DataRow)

For Each r as DataRow In rightDt.Rows
  Dim key = ( r.Field(Of String)("Foo"), r.Field(Of Integer)("Bar") )
  rIndex(key) = r
  allKeys.Add(key)
Next r

Dim lIndex = new Dictionary(Of (ValueTuple(Of String, Integer), DataRow)

For Each r as DataRow In leftDt.Rows
  Dim key = (r.Field(Of String)("Wit"), r.Field(Of Integer)("Woo") )
  lIndex(key) = r
  allKeys.Add(key)
Next r
```

All that remains is to enumerate the allKeys and ask the dictionaries whether they contain it or not and decide what to do

```
For Each k in allKeys
  Dim inL = lIndex.ContainsKey(k)
  Dim inR = rIndex.ContainsKey(k)

  If inL AndAlso inR Then
    Dim updateRo = lIndex(k) 'update the db using this datarow
    ...
  ElseIf inL Then
    Dim insertRo = lIndex(k) 'insert this row to the db
    ...
  Else
    Dim deleteRo = rIndex(k) 'delete this row from the db
    ...
  End If
Next k
```

--

Hah, just realized my brain is still in VB mode. Here's the C# version of the above:

```
var allKeys = new HashSet<(string, int)>();

var rIndex = new Dictionary<(string, int), DataRow>();

foreach(DataRow r in rightDt.Rows){
  var key = (r.Field<string>("Foo"), r.Field<int>("Bar"));
  rIndex[key] = r;
  allKeys.Add(key);
}

var lIndex = new Dictionary<(string, int), DataRow>();

foreach(DataRow r in leftDt.Rows){
  var key = (r.Field<string>("Wit"), r.Field<int>("Woo"));
  lIndex[key] = r;
  allKeys.Add(key);
}

foreach(var k in allKeys){
  var inL = lIndex.ContainsKey(k);
  var inR = rIndex.ContainsKey(k);

  if(inL && inR){
    var updateRo = lIndex[k]; //update the db using this datarow
    ...
  } else if(inL){
    var insertRo = lIndex[k]; //insert this row to the db
    ...
  } else {
    var deleteRo = rIndex[k]; //delete this row from the db
    ...
  }
}
```

You can see a working sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/3jfrPl

Comment: LOL I started coding in VB, didn't even realize i was reading VB till I read your sentence "here it is in C#" >.<. ill try applying this to the dummy data and see what happens, seems correct from what I can understand, I wonder how long it will take though, will be back in a little bit

Comment: Yea this is right, performant and code is much neater